# Android Azure delete all rows

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm building an Android app with an Azure database (in Xamarin), using Azure Mobile Services.
I want to clear a table from it's records.
Although there is a 'table.RemoveAsync', I'm not sure how to select all of the rows.
Is it with 'Select' or 'Where'?
I'd appreciate some assistance.

Here is my code:

```
    //Mobile Service Client reference
    private MobileServiceClient client;

    //Mobile Service sync table used to access data
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Mashlim> mashlimTable;

    const string applicationURL = @"http://blahblah.azurewebsites.net/";


    public override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
        // Mobile Service URL
        client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL);
        await InitLocalStoreAsync();

        // Get the Mobile Service sync table instance to use
        mashlimTable = client.GetSyncTable<Mashlim>();

    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ShabbatMinyan, container, false);
        ….

        OnRefreshItemsSelected();

        return view;
    }

    private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
    {
        // new code to initialize the SQLite store
        string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), localDbFilename);

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path).Dispose();
        }

        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<Mashlim>();

        // Uses the default conflict handler, which fails on conflict
        // To use a different conflict handler, pass a parameter to InitializeAsync. For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=521416
        await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    }

    private async Task SyncAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            await mashlimTable.PullAsync("allMashlims", mashlimTable.CreateQuery()); // query ID is used for incremental sync
        }
        catch (Java.Net.MalformedURLException)
        {
            CreateAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }
    }

    // Called when the refresh menu option is selected
    private async void OnRefreshItemsSelected()
    {
        await SyncAsync(); // get changes from the mobile service
        await RefreshItemsFromTableAsync(); // refresh view using local database
    }

    //Refresh the list with the items in the local database
    private async Task RefreshItemsFromTableAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the items that were marked as mashlim and add them to list
            var list = await mashlimTable.Where(item => item.IsMashlim == true).ToListAsync();

            mashlimim = 0;
            foreach (Mashlim current in list)
                mashlimim++;

            mashlimimNumText.Text = mashlimim.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }
    }

    [Java.Interop.Export()]
    public async void AddItem()
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(Settings.MashlimId==string.Empty)
        {

            // Create a new item
            item = new Mashlim
            {
                Name = nameText.Text,
                PhoneNumber = phoneText.Text,
                IsMashlim = true
            };


            try
            {
                await mashlimTable.InsertAsync(item); // insert the new item into the local database
                await SyncAsync(); // send changes to the mobile service
                await RefreshItemsFromTableAsync();
                Settings.MashlimId = item.Id;
                Settings.MashlimName = item.Name;
                Settings.IsMashlim = true;
                Settings.MashlimPhone = item.PhoneNumber;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Settings.IsMashlim = true;
            item = new Mashlim
            {
                Id = Settings.MashlimId,
                Name = Settings.MashlimName,
                IsMashlim = Settings.IsMashlim,
                PhoneNumber = Settings.MashlimPhone
            };


            try
            {
                await mashlimTable.UpdateAsync(item); // insert the new item into the local database
                await SyncAsync(); // send changes to the mobile service
                await RefreshItemsFromTableAsync();
                mashlim = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the client SDK, you can't run arbitrary SQL statements on the local SQLite store. So, you would have to select all of rows and loop through them to delete. (Be careful about loading everything into memory using ToListAsync, as that might run out of memory on the device.) Note that if you have X rows, this will result in X server requests, which can be pretty slow. See this article for how to do the request on the client: [How to: Delete data in a mobile app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/#deleting).

If you want to delete all rows that match a particular condition, you are better off writing a custom API on the server and having the client just send one request by invoking an API. On the server, you can use either SQL or LINQ, depending on whether you are using .NET or Node.js.

For example, using the .NET backend, you would create a custom API, using [How to: Define a custom API controller](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller).

In one of your controller methods, you would have the following code:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM YOURTABLE WHERE Condition = value");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide some more specific guidance on how to do this (with code), as I am really new to this and unsure what to do. I'm using C#, not Node.js. Thanks!

Comment: If I know that my number of rows won't be more than about 100, should I still not select them all? How do I do this? Thanks?

Comment: @amitairos I've updated my answer with an example of the SQL you'd write on the server. If you have less than 100 rows, it's fine to loop through them on the client using ToListAsync, but you'll still have one server request for each delete operation. If you want to do the operation on the client, then I'd recommend some performance testing.